# Не открывается путь к папке через проводник

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?
При попытке открыть путь к папке через проводник в самой студии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как решить проблему без переустановки.
P.S: На всех новых созданных проектах такая же тема.